# AWS API GW HTTP API with mTLS does not pass multiple cookies in headers

Tags: aws-api-gateway

I have a use case where I want to perform mTLS auth in API GW, and after successful mTLS auth trigger Lambda to generate 3 cookies for CloudFront.

API GW supports mTLS auth at custom domain level.

Here is the problem:

1. When I go to API GW custom domain, which routes to my API/Lambda and should return 3 Set-Cookie heads, browser shows the following after mTLS auth:

```
HTTP/2 302 Found
date: Fri, 04 Dec 2020 05:12:29 GMT
content-length: 0
set-cookie: CloudFront-Policy=1; Domain=; Path=/; HttpOnly
apigw-requestid: XXX
X-Firefox-Spdy: h2
```

2. Now if I go to API endpoint directly (bypassing custom domain and mTLS), I can see that all cookies are set:

```
HTTP/2 302 Found
date: Fri, 04 Dec 2020 05:11:49 GMT
content-length: 0
set-cookie: CloudFront-Policy=1; Domain=; Path=/; HttpOnly
set-cookie: CloudFront-Key-Pair-Id=2; Domain=; Path=/; HttpOnly
set-cookie: CloudFront-Signature=3; Domain=; Path=/; HttpOnly
apigw-requestid: YYY
X-Firefox-Spdy: h2
```

I played around with Lambda payload 1.0 and 2.0, both have the same issue (in 1.0 I also tried the hack of 'set-cookie' in 3 different cases).

Has anyone seen this before / know of a workaround?
Also, has anyone tried to return multiple set-cookie headers using mTLS domain + REST API (my issue above is for HTTP API)?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a workaround yet but I'm seeing the same behavior with a REST API. With mTLS enabled it's limited to one cookie in the response. If I disable mTLS then all the expected cookies make it through.